# Unable to add foreign key constraint after changing char set

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have a table that I'm using to store text messages in an app. I wanted to add the ability to use emojis but they kept showing up as ? ? ? ? etc... in the db. I learned that I needed to changes the character set of my table so I ran the command

`ALTER TABLE posts CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`

but I got this error: `Error Code: 1832. Cannot change column 'user_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'posts_ibfk_2'`

so I dropped the FK and then ran the command and everything worked great. However now, when I try to readd the FK I keep getting a 1215 error that I can't add FK constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE posts
ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES users(id);
```

I tried converting the char set back to what it was originally and am still unable to add the FK. How can I add it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the boldfaced points below, taken from the [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>   central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>   back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
>   table. **The parent and child tables must use the same storage engine**.
>
> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key **must
>   have similar data types**. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. **For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.**
>
> When foreign_key_checks is enabled, which is the default setting,
>   character set conversion is not permitted on tables that include a
>   character string column used in a foreign key constraint.

Basically, after changing the character set and collation of the *referencing* field in the child table; it is not matching with the character set and collation of the *referenced* field in the parent table. You need to ensure that they both match.

So, the Character Set and Collation of the `id` field in the `users` table should be `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_bin` respectively. Am assuming that the datatype of `id` column is `VARCHAR(32)`. You can change it accordingly:

```
ALTER TABLE users 
MODIFY id VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

Comment: is this for mysql or just sql, I'm getting a syntax error 'unexpect SET (set)

Comment: @Kyle you also need to add the datatype. What is the current datatype of `id` column

Comment: I feel like I'm going down a hole of changes, but that gives me the error ```Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'api_keys_ibfk_1' of table 'test_database.api_keys'```

Comment: @Kyle well this definitely seems to be a rabbit hole now. You will have to check the field, which this column is referencing to